# IPN Delivery Status Retrying

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Today all of my IPN have been in Retrying Status. I have no idea why this has suddenly happened. I have checked IPN URL in IPN Settings page as soon as met with this issue. When i try to save my IPN URL  by disabling and enabling it again. Strangely it throws the below error.
"We were unable to validate the URL you have entered. Please check your entry and try again." Any idea on this would be greatly appreciated as my IPN is dead now. Have contacted PayPal tech support, no response either

Answer (score 0):

How old are your ipn listener? 
Have you upgraded your server like reported here? 
https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/

IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS (HTTP will no longer be supported)
TLS 1.2 upgrade (support for TLS 1.0 will be retired)
Merchant API Credential Upgrade (to SHA-256 2048-bit credentials)
SSL Certificate Upgrade

Comment: Thanks . Seems error with Server Side. Now IPN's are sent with HTTP 200 RC.

Comment: Payment just went through, after over 5 hours and 11 retries at PP's end. Nothing changed our end, so pretty serious glitch at PP. So much for reliability!

Comment: @Luca. None of the changes cited in your link seem to be happening on this date (28/09/2016).